# What is the best thing to do with an answer that is wrong, but helpful?

Tags: discussion, wrong-answers

Case in point is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64241062/96944) to a question titled "Flutter dart try catch, catch does not fire".
There are two common reasons in Dart that the catch block won't fire. Half the people landing on this question will be helped by this scenario and the accepted answer. The other half will be helped if they read past the accepted answers and get to a wrong answer. What is the best thing to do:

1. upvote the wrong answer so half the people will find the solution easier
2. create a new question with the same title, but with another scenario and provide the answer
3. edit the wrong answer to say "I know this is not the the problem in the OP's case, but another very common reason for this is ... "
4. Expand the scope of the question so that it also covers the other common case

I don't feel confident to edit people's questions or answers to something that is in essence different from what they said.

Comment: Would it be possible to expand the scope of the question so that it covers that case as well?

Comment: I would go with #2, but ask the OP of the wrong answer to answer it, in a comment on the current answer. Then they'd get credit for the now correct answer, you'd get credit for the question, and everyone gets their magical unicorn points.

Comment: leave it alone and let the votes land where they do.

Comment: There are more than four. E.g., *"5. Open with a comment, trying to engage the answerer to change (e.g., add a qualifying statement) or delete the answer. And see where it leads."* (a ***constructive*** comment—e.g., avoiding using "you" and concentrate on the content, not the answerer's actions)), *"6. Flag as [NAA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420)"*, and "*7. Add a comment to the answer to guide future readers.*" (e.g, if 5. does not work).

Comment: I like #3 a lot personally; the answer sounds like it clearly contains information that's broadly useful, and even applicable to the specific subject area of the question, just not OP's specific case. If a note makes sense, then add it– but frankly, if it's "correct" in the sense that the information is accurate but "wrong" in the sense that it just gets some details in the question wrong, then it may not need an edit at all, especially if users are still finding it useful.

Comment: It would be either #2 or #3 for me, but #2 only if you write a new better answer yourself. Answer duplication is a no-no.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Wrong answers shouldn’t be flagged as _NAA_, so I don’t think the proposed sixth option makes sense here.

Comment: The post was simply plagiarised, from https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/160. In other words, the whole text was written for an entirely different context. Because it was plagiarised, we deleted it.